# JAVA paint an arch with math formula

Tags: java, math, formula, game-physics

i have to do an exercise of java swing.

- draw a simple circle/ball (done)
- move a circle (done)
- from a starting point (half of jpanel(x),0(y)) move this circle/ball that follow an arch direction and bounce when the circle touch the end of screen side (in my case the window it's only x: 0-300 y: 0-300, it's a very little windows)
  when the screen end (see picture that i have linked below) continue to bounce in arch movement following the sides of screen until ball return in initial position,no need to be exactly initial position but bounce must is infinite and continuosly(sorry for my english)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfVho.jpg

what's the function that i need for doing an arch movement? i can't use graphic2d or existent class in java, i need function to apply for x,y for move this ball

i know arch formula from mathematic but i don't know how apply in java in this case, i think i need a function for get all points  of a arch position and then i can apply to x and y for move the ball.

help
i have this code

```
public class Ani2 extends JPanel implements Runnable{

private final int DELAY =105;
public Ani2(){
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setSize(300,300);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.add(this);
    jf.setVisible(true);

}
private Thread animator;
int x=150, y=150;


@Override
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    animator = new Thread(this);
    animator.start();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(red);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.fillOval(x,y, 20, 20);
    g.dispose();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Ani2();
}

    @Override
    public void run() {
    long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

    beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (true) {


         x += 1;
         y -= 1;


        repaint();

        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
        sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

        if (sleep < 0)
            sleep = 2;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that "arch function" means physics.

Imagine your ball sitting at rest on a ledge at height `h` above a surface.  The ball has mass `m`; gravity exerts a force on the ball equal to `m*g` in the down direction.

The equations of motion for the ball are:

```
F = m*a
```

This is a vector equation, because force, acceleration, velocity, and displacement are all vector quantities.

I can use calculus to solve for the distance the ball falls from the height after giving it a push in the positive x-direction (initial x-velocity).

The result will be a quadratic equation.